# pexpect password entry from tkinter dialog

Tags: python, tkinter, pexpect

I am calling pexpect with a sudo command thus:
`lssubproc = pexpect.spawn('sudo ls /dev/')`

The pexpect process expects a password thus:
`lssubproc.expect('\[sudo\] password for .*\: ')`

Is there any way to redirect the password I get from my tkinter dialog box (below) to the pexpect.expect function?

`passwd = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter password:", show='*')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Don't you simply want to do `lssubproc.sendline(passwd)` after the expect() call?